# How can I draw a circle behind another circle on the same line slope?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a line and a circle at the end of the line, like in this image:

[image: Line with Circles]

I draw the first circle and center this circle is end of first line.
How can I draw another circle behind the first one and on the same slope of line? I tried this code:

```
float y2 = m * x - m * x1 + y1;  //new 
p1 = new PointF(x1, y1);  //x and y for first line line
PointF p2 = new PointF();
p2 = new PointF(x2, y2); //make the new  x,y as point
g.DrawLine(penTow, p1, p2); //this should draw line from center first circle to center of second circle
g.DrawEllipse(penOrginal,
    (float)(p2.X - radius), (float)(p2.Y - radius),
    (float)(radius * 2), (float)(radius * 2)); //draw the second circle and center is the end of second line
```

When I tried it the circle was too far from the first circle

Comment: You tried that code....and?

Comment: the secnd circle become to far

Comment: Can you provide a picture of how it should look?

Comment: sure one moment

Comment: this picture https://thumb.ibb.co/eaBV56/uiii.jpg

Comment: it's should be like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eQhG.jpg][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var slope = Math.Atan2(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
    var nextX = p2.X + radus * 2 * Math.Sin(slope);
    var nextY = p2.Y + radus * 2 * Math.Cos(slope);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black,
                          (float)(nextX - radus), (float)(nextY - radus),
                          (float)(radus * 2), (float)(radus * 2));
```

Comment: p2 still unknow only (x1,y1) and x2,y2 is unknow
i want to find the x2 and y2
thax

Comment: the line 2 shoul be from the center of the first cirle to the center of the secend circlr
and the center of the first circle is the end of line 1
which mean i had the x1,y1 for the secend line and i just need x2,y1
cindtion : the new line must be in the same slope of the first line 
and the length of line 2 must be equal radius*2

Comment: Your code above draws a line and a circle. If you add my code below you will see that it draws the second circle as in your picture. Have you tried it?